# Go-Ethereum: Any Getter for the field "from" in the type Transaction in types/transaction.go?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm building a consensus engine for Ethereum in Go-Ethereum. In it (one way to create it), validators make a transaction to a validator contract each block they produce. Then, to verify that during block validation by everyone else, they use ethapi.DoCall to check if the transaction succeeded (no easy way to access receipts via the Engine interface, nor easy way to access statedb for the block being validated if I only use what interface provides, so easiest to rerun the transaction). This requires that the validators find the transaction, and for that, they need to iterate through all transactions in a block, until they find one from the block signer. For that, I need to check who a transaction is from. That data is conveniently already cached, in Transaction.from field, but it is unexported and I cannot see any getter. Is there any way to access it (without changing codebase)? Or do I need to recover the sender from scratch?

**Edit:** I assume such getter would not exist if the "from" cache is predicted to not be reliable. Still interested in if it exists, if it does not I'll just recover the sender.